# Oracle tns listener error

Tags: windows, oracle, dbm

I've just installed Oracle 10g When I try to connect to oracle db i get an error:

> could not start OracleOraHome92TNSListener

when i got to services and try to start it, it says that the file doesnt exist. the service file is C:\oracle\ora92\BIN\TNSLSNR (TNSLSNR is a file not a directory)

C:\oracle\ora92\BIN\TNSLSNR  doesn't exist on my machine at all. do you know how to get it?

> Could not start the Oracle Ora92 Listener service on Local Computer.Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 3):

Here's a couple of issues I see.  You say you installed 10g but the error is a 9.2 error.  It could be that your computer already had an Oracle 9i on it that was mis-configured or uninstalled and that is leading to the error.

You need to check your disk and find the ORACLE_HOME (directory) where Oracle 10g was installed.  Once you find that you can adjust the PATH and ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN environment variables to point to the right place.  This should allow you to start the database and the listener.

If you need to install the Oracle Client for 10g then this information below will be helpful as well.

The Oracle client can be installed separately. Just go to this address, download the client and unzip it into a subdirectory and then run the Oracle Universal Installer by running setup.exe from the directory.

[Oracle Downloads Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database10g/downloads/index.html)

Comment: @user521180 the TNS_ADMIN variable usually points to the same place as ORACLE_HOME. The important thing is that tnsnames.ora is in the directory you specify as TNS_ADMIN

Comment: Agree. THe installation probably screwed up an older configuration.

Comment: TNS_ADMIN usually points to the directory where the tnsnames.ora is located